# Is there an easier way to write this function and only using prelude from Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I'm pretty new to Haskell, and are trying to solve an assignment, I've solved it, but I'm wondering if there is an easier or prettier way to make a function do the same as my `wordChange`. I'm trying to only use what is already in prelude.

```
dictionaryChecker _ [] = False
dictionaryChecker word (x:xs) = if elem word (snd x) then True else dictionaryChecker word xs

wordChange :: String -> String 
wordChange str = unwords (map (\s -> if length (translate s) > 0 then (translate s) 
else if (dictionaryChecker s dictionary) then concat (replicate (length s) "*")
else s) (words str))

translate :: String -> String 
translate str = contains str dictionary

contains _ [] = ""
contains str (x:xs) = if elem str (snd x) then fst x else contains str xs
```

Comment: Could you explain the assignment?

Comment: @bereal I'm supposed to change the word in a string that are in a given dictionary. So if i write ```wordChange "Haskell is excellent and Julia is nice"```  I would get ``` "Haskell is doubleplusgood and ***** is nice" ```  Since excellent and Julia are in the dictionary

Comment: @SonCOR edit the question to add the assignment resume. Also, your snippet of code doesn't work because `dictionary` is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the `lookup` function from `Prelude`, which takes a key and a list of tuples (a.k.a a dictionary) and returns `Maybe value`. This simplfies your function a lot. Also, if changeWord uses a dictionary, it should be explicit instead of using a global variable. Below, a partial solution: since it is an assignment I think you should try to complete it ;)

```
changeWord :: [(String, String)] -> String -> String
changeWord dic s = unwords $ substitute ws
  where -- ws is just the list of words s has  
        ws = words s
        -- the function substitute does the word changing recursively. Try to complete it
        substitute []     = []
        substitute (x:xs) = 
         case lookup x dic of -- look for x in the dictionary and returns the value if found
           Nothing -> undefined --complete
           Just y  -> undefined --complete
```

Answer (score 2):

An obfuscated answer: earn a gold star from your professor if you can explain how it works, and be accused of copying from the internet if you can't:

```
wordChange :: [(String, String)] -> String -> String
wordChange dict = unwords . map (foldr const <*> (`lookup` dict)) . words
```

Comment: are you abusing `(->)`'s `Applicative` instance **and** `Maybe`'s `Foldable` instance at the same time?

Comment: I knew you'd like it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dictionaryChecker` is in essence an [**`any :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) with `elem word . snd` as condition:

```
dictionaryChecker :: (Foldable f, Foldable g, Eq a) => a -> f (b, g a) -> Bool
dictionaryChecker word = any (elem word . snd)
```

as for a `translate`, we can work with a [section of an infix operator [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) to make a point-free function:

```
translate :: String -> String 
translate = (`contains` dictionary)
```

and for `contains` we can work with a [**`foldr :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr)

```
contains :: (Foldable f, Foldable g, Eq a) => a -> f (String, g a) -> String
contains str = foldr (\x y -> if … then … else …) ""
```

I leave implementing the `…` parts as an exercise.

Comment: this is the only answer that uses the correct type for the dictionary, and thus the `contains` function, which is implied by OP code `contains str (x:xs) = if elem str (snd x) then fst x  ...`. it's unnecessarily general though, because `contains _ [] = ""` line in OP code is an error;  it is clearly implied to be `contains str [] = str` by the Q body.